# Problema ao passar do Controller para Model

Tags: java, mvc, view, controller

Estou fazendo um código, onde envolve MVC.
Para passar do *View* para o *Controller* não estou tendo problemas,
porém quando vou passar do *Controller* para o *Model* eu não consigo,
sendo que a variável é importada, mas sem valor algum.

View:

```
package bancomvc;

public class View {

    public static int valor;
    public static String nome;
    public static double saque;
    public static double limite;
    public static int opcao;

    public void exibeMenu() {

        System.out.println("\t Escolha a opção desejada");
        System.out.println("1 - Depositar");
        System.out.println("2 - Sacar");
        System.out.println("3 - Sair\n");
        System.out.print("Opção: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        opcao = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Digite o valor:");
        valor = scan.nextInt();

    }

    public void setOpcao(int opcao) {
        this.opcao = opcao;
    }

    public int getOpcao() {
        return opcao;
    }

    public void setValor(int valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public int getValor() {
        return valor;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
package bancomvc;

public class Controller {

    public static int recValor;
    public static int opc;

    public void Valores() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        View cliente = new View();

        opc = cliente.opcao;
        recValor = cliente.valor;

        System.out.println(opc);

    }

    public void setOpc(int valor) {
        this.opc = valor;
    }

    public int getOpc() {
        return opc;
    }

    public void setValor(int valor) {
        this.recValor = valor;
    }

    public int getrecValor() {
        return recValor;

    }
```

Model:

```
package bancomvc;

public class Model {

    public static int op;
    public static int val;
    public static int Saldo;

    public void execução() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        Controller ctrl = new Controller();

        op = ctrl.opc;
        val = ctrl.recValor;
        System.out.println(op);

    }
```

BancoMVC(Classe principal):

```
package bancomvc;

public class BancoMVC {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        View ver = new View();
        ver.exibeMenu();
        Model mod = new Model();
        mod.execução();
        Controller cont = new Controller();
        cont.Valores();

    }
}
```

O *Get* e *Set* provavelmente estou usando indevidamente, se alguém puder me mostrar o caminho das pedras eu agradeço :) (Ainda sou iniciante).

Comment: **Algumas dúvidas:** Suas classes de controle e modelo estão sem as últimas chaves, isso ocorreu quando você colou o código aqui? — Na classe de visão você está usando um `Scanner` sem importá-lo. O Java não sabe o que é um "*Scanner*" até que você aponte em qual pacote ele está (no caso, `java.util`), foi um esquecimento?

Comment: Não, eu enxuguei um pouco o código com algumas coisas que não seriam necessarias aqui, pode notar que tirei todas as importações, o cóodigo não apresenta erros, mas o resultado no model das variaveis ficam nulas...

Comment: @MatheusLopes Se a resposta abaixo serviu a você, marque-a como aceita para que o Dener possa ganhar pontos com isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MatheusLopes acho que é só a ordem que você está chamando o Model.executa() e o Controller.Valores() na classe BancoMVC, experimenta trocar para algo assim:

```
public class BancoMVC {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        View ver = new View();
        ver.exibeMenu();
        Controller cont = new Controller();
        cont.Valores();//chame esse primeiro
        Model mod = new Model();
        mod.execução();//depois esse

    }
}
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo, poxa, obg :) , achava que nao tinha sequencia em relação a isso :D